# error in GAM model with raster predictor

Tags: r, raster, gam, mgcv

Though this problem has been discussed at stackoverflow, I am not really clear how to address my specific case

I have a raster file which I read in as:

```
prec<-raster("R:/rsrch/model/prec.tif")
summary(prec)
            prec
Min.         3.0
1st Qu.     52.0
Median     104.5
3rd Qu.    173.0
Max.      1850.0
NA's     19201.0
```

My response is presence and absence (coded as 1 and 0 respectively) (total 9674 points). I built a `gam` model using the package `mgcv` as follows:

```
mdl<-gam(species ~ s(prec), family=binomial)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = species ~ 1 + prec,drop.unused.levels = TRUE): 
 invalid type (S4) for variable 'prec'
```

I think this error is being caused by the NA's in my raster. If you remove the NAs, the total number of grids is equal to the number of presence-absence points. I am not sure what to do now:

One thing I tried was this:

```
prec1<-values(prec)[!is.na(values(prec))]
```

This removed the NAs from my raster but after I run the model, it comes with some really funny graphs which I am totally sure is wrong. Any advise on how to run a gam when the predictor is raster and response is a vector. I have X Y coordinates of the response in the same projection as my raster. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your response variable is a data frame and the predictor is a raster. Extract the  values of the raster for the points, put them all together in a data frame then run the model.